# Find $a$ such as $f(x)=a$ has solution in $(0,1]$

Tags: calculus, functions

$f\colon (0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$

$$f(x)=x^n - n\ln x + 1$$ where $n\neq 0$, $n\in\mathbb{N} $.

If $f(x) = a$ given, find $a$, such as $x ∈ (0,1] $.

I tried to build $f$, starting from $0 < x ⩽ 1$ $=>$ $ 0< x^n ⩽ 1$

But, I have some problems including $n \ln x$.

Is there any other more elegant option?

Comment: Without much work, just examine the function at the end points. At $x = 1, f(1) = 2$. Now, if you examne $x \to 0$, you'll observe that $f(x) \to \infty$. Since $f$ is continuous, it at least takes all values in $[2, \infty]$. Hence if $a$ is in that range, then  there should exist at least one solution

Comment: Using the Intermediate Value Theorem

Comment: More, the $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}-\frac{n}{x}$ sign do not change on $(0,1]$, indeed $nx^{n-1}-\frac{n}{x}=0\Rightarrow x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow x^{n}=1$ so $f(x)$ can't reach below $f(1)$

Answer (score 1):

Putting $y=x^n$ or $y^{\frac{1}{n}}=x$ we get :

$$y-\ln(y)+1$$

But your equality says :

$$y-\ln(y)+1=a$$

Or :$$y-\ln(y)+1-a=0$$

But :$$y-1\geq \ln(y)\quad \forall y>0$$ (you can prove it using exponential and derivative )

With equality if $y=1$ so we find $a\leq -2$